# Custom ASP.NET Core route with id and title separated by hyphen

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

In ASP.NET Core, I want to generate some kind of SEO-URLs, that contains the id of an entry and also his title.

Example: example.com/News/ViewNews/123-test-news

In Startup.cs I defined the following Route

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "SeoNews",
                template: "{controller=News}/{action=ViewNews}/{id:int}-{title}"
            );
```

In the News-Controller, the following Action exists

```
        public IActionResult ViewNews(int id, string title) { }
```

The breakpoint inside gave me empty values, so id = 0 and title = null.

Calling

Example: example.com/News/ViewNews/123

Gave me id = 123, but empty title cause it's not present in the URL. Whats wrong with my Rewrite-Route?

Other Routes I've defined **after** my custom route:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AreaRoute",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultMVCRoute",
                template: "{controller=Dashboard}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
```

**EDIT**
I tried replacing the hyphen with a slash like SO do, so the routing template is `{controller=News}/{action=ViewNews}/{id:int}/{title}`. That works perfectly.. Can't understand why. I already tried to escape the hyphen, cause it may conflicts as special char from regular expressions, which doesn't work too.

Using a slash as delimitter is a suiteable workaround for me. But I'm interested to know what's special on this char, that it doesn't work, so I renamed the question title.

Comment: Did you add this above your default route?

Comment: Yes, I've the Area and default MVC route defined after my custom one and added their code in the first post.

Comment: How will it behave if you try `example.com/News/ViewNews/123-testnews` url?

Comment: For one, title in your above route is a mandatory parameter not an optional. Second you can use * to mark slug/remaining of the url (i.e. {*slug} and everything after it will be matched for it)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean slug instead of title? Title would imply that you want to use it as parameter. A slug is only there for the sake of having a more describable URL, but isn't actually used in the real routing.

This case is very well documented in the ASP.NET Core documentation already in the "[Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)" article.

> You can use the * character as a prefix to a route parameter to bind to the rest of the URI - this is called a catch-all parameter. For example, `blog/{*slug}` would match any URI that started with `/blog` and had any value following it (which would be assigned to the slug route value). Catch-all parameters can also match the empty string.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "SeoNews",
            template: "{controller=News}/{action=ViewNews}/{id:int}/{*slug}"
        );
```

One reason why `{controller=News}/{action=ViewNews}/{id:int}-{title}` doesn't work is that `title` is not optional. Second is it tries to match the whole pattern between the slashes, so you can just have one parameter per segment.

You could also try this, but I doubt it will work

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "SeoNews",
            template: "{controller=News}/{action=ViewNews}/{id:int}{*slug}"
        );
```